# Exception whilst running all unit tests at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a bunch of unit tests in unit test class.

When I run each one individually, they all pass, but when I run them all at the same time, the first one passes and the rest fail:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added

Could anyone tell me why? And how I need to remedy the error?

Sample:

```
 public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    #region Additional test attributes
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    ///A test for SplitTdsName
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void SplitTdsNameTest_SimpleValidName1()
    {            
        string tdsName = "Mr Daniel Trunley";
        MemberName expected = new MemberName("Mr", "Daniel", "Trunley");
        MemberName actual;
        actual = TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName(tdsName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);            
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///A test for SplitTdsName
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void SplitTdsNameTest_SimpleValidName2()
    {
        string tdsName = "Mr Daniel George Trunley";
        MemberName expected = new MemberName("Mr", "Daniel George", "Trunley");
        MemberName actual;
        actual = TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName(tdsName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void SplitTdsNameTest_SimpleValidName3()
    {
        string tdsName = "Daniel George Trunley";
        MemberName expected = new MemberName("", "", "Daniel George Trunley");
        MemberName actual;
        actual = TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName(tdsName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

The remaining tests are all of the same type.

Comment: You don't have any TestInitialize Attributed methods do you?

Comment: @fauxtrot no I don't, I'm relatively new to UnitTesting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tests not following *Independent* principle, so one test should not affect other tests.

Looking in the code you've provided I can assume that the problem that 
`TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName()` cache some data. I would suggest cleanup all shared variables:

```
[TestCleanup()]
public void Cleanup()
{
   // cleanup all shared variables     
}
```

Useful links:

- [Properties of Good Tests: A-TRIP](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/10/25/properties-of-good-tests-a-trip/)

Comment: I'm relatively new to unit testing, I don't know what I'd put inside this cleanup method?

Comment: @user1016253 : I believe TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName() updates some static fields/properties of TdsTransformer class, am I right?

Comment: @sll 1+ for 10k reputation :)

Comment: This answer actually helped me. Under my test methods, main form was being initialised in order to call a public method subject for testing. There was some code under main form's initialisation branching to other classes' methods where I realised some static variables got introduced by my peers. I didn't know what to include under Cleanup method as those static variables were internal to another class but I skipped the static variable initialisation on main form initialisation for the calls made from my unit tests (WinForms).